# Calculation of sequences of values in a single column in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

[image]
I have this data for many players this is an example of one player. Data represent time series of losses
and wins . When I use this code

```
rle(example$win_status)$lengths
```

I can see that a player has series 2 losses then 1 wins etc. But this is just vector of consecutive
occurences of a value in win_status column. I would like to have a dataframe with playerid,win_status,
number of of consecutive occurences which are values supplied by above code.

Second thing is that before a player stopped playing he had series of 21 losses so I know if someone provide mi with a solution for above problem I can figure it out as a last row of a data frame but separate solution would be nice as well.

Though I am working with binary win_status I would like to have more generalizable solution which would work also for
a variable with more categories. I hope my explanation of a problem is clear..
Help is much appreciated...

`example<-structure(list(Src_player_Id = c(10274870, 10274870, 10274870,  10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870,  10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870,  10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870,  10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870, 10274870),  placed_datetime = structure(c(1580358268.23252, 1580358485.28439,  1580362947.22817, 1580365006.9802, 1580368726.16779, 1580369953.98473,  1580411950.92812, 1580412379.18781, 1580418850.81781, 1580432581.57936,  1580432955.15843, 1580504609.41338, 1580504901.15106, 1580505161.11841,  1580562945.16703, 1580563140.89132, 1580563351.21689, 1580563484.11476,  1580571123.17468, 1580845296.86797, 1580845843.91141, 1580846042.87572,  1580846145.12245, 1580935028.38694, 1580935120.13632, 1581517395.39957,  1581522889.1296, 1581523347.03016, 1581523609.88115, 1581545860.32047 ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), win_status = c("Loss",  "Loss", "Win", "Loss", "Win", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Win",  "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss",  "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss",  "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss", "Loss")), class = c("spec_tbl_df",  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rleid` that creates the id column.  After grouping by 'Src_player_Id', can create new grouping column with `rleid` on 'win_status' and get the frequency count with `count`

```
library(dplyr) #1.0.0
library(data.table)
example %>% 
    # grouped by 'Src_player_id'
    group_by(Src_player_Id) %>%
    # create more grouping columns and specify the `.add = TRUE`
    group_by(new = rleid(win_status), win_status, .add = TRUE) %>% 
    # frequency count
    count %>%
    # remove the group attributes
    ungroup %>%
    # remove the unwanted columns
    select(-new)
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  Src_player_Id win_status     n
#          <dbl> <chr>      <int>
#1      10274870 Loss           2
#2      10274870 Win            1
#3      10274870 Loss           1
#4      10274870 Win            1
#5      10274870 Loss           3
#6      10274870 Win            1
#7      10274870 Loss          21
```

---

Or `rep`licate the sequence of `values` with the `lengths` from `rle`

```
example %>% 
    group_by(Src_player_Id) %>%
    group_by( 
         new = with(rle(win_status), 
            rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), win_status, .add = TRUE) %>% 
    count %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-new)
```

---

To create a flag where there are 21 or more 'loss'

```
example %>% 
    group_by(Src_player_Id) %>%
    group_by(grp = rleid(win_status), .add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(flag = n() >= 21 & all(win_status == 'Loss')) 
#  Src_player_Id     placed_datetime win_status grp  flag
#1       10274870 2020-01-30 04:24:28       Loss   1 FALSE
#2       10274870 2020-01-30 04:28:05       Loss   1 FALSE
#3       10274870 2020-01-30 05:42:27        Win   2 FALSE
#4       10274870 2020-01-30 06:16:46       Loss   3 FALSE
#5       10274870 2020-01-30 07:18:46        Win   4 FALSE
#6       10274870 2020-01-30 07:39:13       Loss   5 FALSE
#7       10274870 2020-01-30 19:19:10       Loss   5 FALSE
#8       10274870 2020-01-30 19:26:19       Loss   5 FALSE
#9       10274870 2020-01-30 21:14:10        Win   6 FALSE
#10      10274870 2020-01-31 01:03:01       Loss   7  TRUE
#11      10274870 2020-01-31 01:09:15       Loss   7  TRUE
#12      10274870 2020-01-31 21:03:29       Loss   7  TRUE
#13      10274870 2020-01-31 21:08:21       Loss   7  TRUE
#14      10274870 2020-01-31 21:12:41       Loss   7  TRUE
#15      10274870 2020-02-01 13:15:45       Loss   7  TRUE
#16      10274870 2020-02-01 13:19:00       Loss   7  TRUE
#17      10274870 2020-02-01 13:22:31       Loss   7  TRUE
#18      10274870 2020-02-01 13:24:44       Loss   7  TRUE
#19      10274870 2020-02-01 15:32:03       Loss   7  TRUE
#20      10274870 2020-02-04 19:41:36       Loss   7  TRUE
#21      10274870 2020-02-04 19:50:43       Loss   7  TRUE
#22      10274870 2020-02-04 19:54:02       Loss   7  TRUE
#23      10274870 2020-02-04 19:55:45       Loss   7  TRUE
#24      10274870 2020-02-05 20:37:08       Loss   7  TRUE
#25      10274870 2020-02-05 20:38:40       Loss   7  TRUE
#26      10274870 2020-02-12 14:23:15       Loss   7  TRUE
#27      10274870 2020-02-12 15:54:49       Loss   7  TRUE
#28      10274870 2020-02-12 16:02:27       Loss   7  TRUE
#29      10274870 2020-02-12 16:06:49       Loss   7  TRUE
#30      10274870 2020-02-12 22:17:40       Loss   7  TRUE
```

Comment: Hi Akrun I actually added excel printscreen what is a required output, even though with your mutated column which is "changes counter" I would be able to take it from there ..